# window.location.href doesn't redirect

Tags: javascript, dom-events, window.location

I know this is a question much discussed but I can't figure out why it does not work for me.

This is my function:

```
function ShowComments(){

 alert("fired");
 var movieShareId = document.getElementById('movieId');
 //alert("found div" + movieShareId.textContent || movieShareId.innerText);
 //alert("redirect location: /comments.aspx?id=" + movieShareId.textContent || movieShareId.innerText + "/");
 window.location.href = "/comments.aspx?id=" + movieShareId.textContent || movieShareId.innerText + "/";
 var newLocation = window.location;
 //alert("full location: " + window.location);

}
```

If I have the alerts uncommented or if I have Mozilla's bugzilla open it works fine, otherwise it does not redirect to the other page.

Any ideas why?

Comment: What's the point of ` var newLocation = window.location;` ? No line should be executed after the window.location change.

Comment: How are you calling the function? Are you doing something else at that point that may interfer with the change of location?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent mailto event from opening a new tab in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457684/how-to-prevent-mailto-event-from-opening-a-new-tab-in-browser)

Answer (score 94):

If you are calling this function through a submit button. This may be the reason why the browser does not redirect. It will run the code in the function and then submit the page instead of redirect. In this case change the type tag of your button.

Comment: Thanks. Helped a lot. I had my button 'type' as 'submit'. Changed it to 'reset' and it worked.

Comment: Exctly, the problem of this sorts, is often due to the click or 'enter'-event bubbeling up, and submitting the form.

Comment: You absolutely made my day. 12h of google and stackoverflow searching for that. Top.

Comment: Interestingly enough, even if my button was not `submit`, it didn't work cause it was inside a form. I had to move it outside then it worked.

Comment: This was my issue for a button that had NO type call out, putting type='button' fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I was using `onclick` in a link but wasn't working. Changing link to `button` worked!

Comment: Dude thank you so much, I've been trying to find this for hours!

Comment: The default behavior of a `<button />` if inside a `<form />` is always the `submit` behavior. 

In order to do front-end manipulations in ReactJs land,  using the `<button type"button" />` is the solution! Thanks ! 

[See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type)

Comment: To add here, if you still want to have `button[type=submit]` and handle the redirection in the `form`'s `submit` event, you can also call `event.preventDefault()` in the event handler--setting `window.location.href` should then properly redirect.

Comment: thats totally true, thanks for your solution which let me also understand submit concept and its effects

Answer (score 37):

From this answer,

[window.location.href not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300674/window-location-href-not-working)

you just need to add

```
return false;
```

at the bottom of your function

Comment: didnt work for me

Comment: Adding this destroyed the redirect.

Answer (score 9):

Some parenthesis are missing.

Change

```
 window.location.href = "/comments.aspx?id=" + movieShareId.textContent || movieShareId.innerText + "/";
```

to

```
 window.location = "/comments.aspx?id=" + (movieShareId.textContent || movieShareId.innerText) + "/";
```

No priority is given to the `||` compared to the `+`.

Remove also everything after the `window.location` assignation : this code isn't supposed to be executed as the page changes.

Note: you don't need to set `location.href`. It's enough to just set `location`.

Comment: @user2235124 There are other problems in your page, I think. And the fact you have some code after the location assignment makes me suspect bigger logical problems. Can you build a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com) showing your issue ?

Answer (score 8):

Solution from here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/727493/JavaScript-document-location-href-not-working

```
document.location.href = 'Your url',true;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't use `window.location.replace` or `document.location.href` or any of your favourite vanilla javascript methods to redirect a page **to itself**.

So if you're dynamically adding in the redirect path from the back end, or pulling it from a data tag, make sure you do check at some stage for redirects to the current page. It could be as simple as:

```
if(window.location.href == linkout)
{
    location.reload();
}
else
{
    window.location.href = linkout;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you're not sending a '#' at the end of your URL. In my case, that was preventing window.location.href from working.

Comment: yea same here, isn't there any native overcome to the issue?

Comment: Note, the redirect with a hash will work if you are including it before or without any querystring parameters.

Answer (score 4):

I'll give you one nice function for this problem:

```
function url_redirect(url){
    var X = setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.replace(url);
        return true;
    },300);

    if( window.location = url ){
        clearTimeout(X);
        return true;
    } else {
        if( window.location.href = url ){
            clearTimeout(X);
            return true;
        }else{
            clearTimeout(X);
            window.location.replace(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

This is universal working solution for the `window.location` problem. Some browsers go into problem with `window.location.href` and also sometimes can happen that `window.location` fail. That's why we also use `window.location.replace()` for any case and timeout for the "last try".

Answer (score 3):

`window.location.replace` is the best way to emulate a redirect:

```
function ShowComments(){
    var movieShareId = document.getElementById('movieId');
    window.location.replace("/comments.aspx?id=" + (movieShareId.textContent || movieShareId.innerText) + "/");
}
```

More information about why `window.location.replace` is the best javascript redirect can be found [**right here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript).

Comment: The point made in the answer you link to is about the trace in history. I don't see how it's relevant.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it is working as expected for all browsers after setting time interval.

```
setTimeout(function(){document.location.href = "myNextPage.html";},100);
```

Answer (score 0):

window.location.href wasn't working in Android.
I cleared cache in Android Chrome and it works fine.
Suggest trying this first before getting involved in various coding.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your api route, make sure you are not missing a response such as

```
res.status(200).json(data);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).