# Javascript mailto using window open

Tags: javascript

I currently have a form set up with 5 radio options. I have a switch statement depending on the option you pick and that determines where the email is going to go.

Inside my switch, I have this piece of code.

```
window.open("mailto:"+emailTo+'?cc='+emailCC+'&subject='+emailSub+'&body='+emailBody);
```

It all works fine when it opens up my email client with all of the content however it also opens a blank page in the browser.

Is there another way to achieve this or prevent a blank window from opening but still make it as if you clicked on the href:mailto ?

Comment: I think this is a browser setting, therefore you have no control over how this works.

Comment: You may use `window.location.href = "mailto:mail@example.org";` but this will work only if in browser setting Gmail opening is not setted, etc.

Comment: You can just close that window, can't you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent mailto event from opening a new tab in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457684/how-to-prevent-mailto-event-from-opening-a-new-tab-in-browser)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Instead of:

```
window.open("mailto:"+emailTo+'?cc='+emailCC+'&subject='+emailSub+'&body='+emailBody);
```

You can try:

```
location.href = "mailto:"+emailTo+'?cc='+emailCC+'&subject='+emailSub+'&body='+emailBody;
```

Answer (score 35):

The second argument in window.open is the target.

`window.open('mailto:'+emailTo+'?cc='+emailCC+'&subject='+emailSub+'&body='+emailBody, '_self');` should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Location.href doesn't seem to work in chrome.
I do it like this:

```
x=window.open("mailstring");
x.close();
```

Works perfect for me.

Comment: you should not put mailstring into apostrophs if you mean it as a variable or place-holder

Comment: This will not work consistently. On my machine it sometimes closes the window before the mailto completes.

Comment: Doesn't work for me if outlook is the mail client

Answer (score -5):

After your "window.open" statement, try running an "if statement" to check and see if a new window was opened so that it will close.

```
if (win && win.open && !win.closed) 
    {   
    win.close();
    }
```

This will happen very fast so the users might notice that a window opened and closed before the email application opened.